# Extract pdf content and convert it in word or csv

Tags: php, html

I am a starter.
I have a pdf file.
I want a php program wherein i can extract the content of pdf and output it in word or csv.

Comment: Good luck with this!

Comment: If you are a 'starter' then Google is your best friend. Doing a quick search you can find this library which seems to be doing what you want: http://www.pdfparser.org

Comment: thanks titi pdf parser worked!!

Comment: one more help i need the data to be in a table form or in a excel sheet would also do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To read PDF files, you will need to install the [XPDF](http://www.foolabs.com/xpdf/about.html) package, which includes "pdftotext." Once you have XPDF/pdftotext installed, you run the following PHP statement to get the PDF text:

```
content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$filename.' -');
```

After getting the content, Download [PHPDOCX](http://www.phpdocx.com/) Community version, try like this.

```
<?php
require_once '../../classes/CreateDocx.inc';

$docx = new CreateDocx();
$textInfo = $content;

$paramsTextInfo = array(
    'val' => 1,
    'i' => 'single',
    'sz' => 8
);

$docx->addText($textInfo, $paramsTextInfo);

$docx->createDocx('report.docx');
?>
```

Comment: thanks guys !! PDFPARSER helped me alot!!